# What is the j-invariant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I know that it has something to do with Elliptic Curves in the Complex Plane but I don't have an intuitive sense as to what its there for.

I understand it is defined in terms of multiple Einstein series and is a modular form of weight $0$ but outside of that, I am really confused about this function.

If someone can explain the j-invariant without having to go over the entire subject of Elliptic Curves that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part of the Wikipedia article [j-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) are you confused about?

Comment: You do need to understand some elliptic function theory in order to make sense of the j-invariant. The interesting aspect of this invariant is that it takes algebraic values for certain values of the argument. There are other aspects of the theory but this one is simpler to comprehend.

Comment: isn't this one of those questions where you could write books to answer it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me give a crude answer not in the language of complex analysis but in purely down-to-earth algebraic terms.

If you have a plane curve $E$ of genus one given by an equation $Y^2=X^3+aX+b$, there’s a rational expression $j(a,b)\in\Bbb Q(a,b)$ with this property: if you have another curve $E'$ given as $Y^2=X^3+a'X+b'$, then over an algebraic closure of the field containing the coefficients, $E$ and $E'$ are isomorphic if and only if $j(a,b)=j(a',b')$.

The above is imprecise and sloppy, but good enough for an appreciation of what $j$ does: it classifies the elliptic curve $E$, but unfortunately only over an algebraically closed field. Two curves with $\Bbb Q$-coefficients can have the same $j$-invariant, but not be isomorphic until you make a finite extension of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did see on wikipedia that it has something to do with the parametization of elliptic curves but did not quite understand what that meant.

Comment: What is the definition of isomorphic used here?

Comment: I guess that’d be: via a biholomorphic mapping, defined over the field ($\Bbb Q$, or whatever) in  question.